# Have problem when trying calculate jacobian matrix from nonlinear system of equations

Tags: python, numpy, calculus, autograd

I found code for compute jacobian matrix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553006/compute-the-jacobian-matrix-in-python) and try it for non-linear system of equations.

```
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import jacobian

x = np.array([1,2], dtype=float)

def fs(x,y):
  return np.array([x + 2*y - 2, x**2 + 4*y**2 - 4])

jacobian_cost = jacobian(fs)

jacobian_cost(x[0],x[1])
```

But instead of outputting result like this

```
array([ 1.  2.]
 [ 2. 16.])
```

it outputting result like this

```
array([1., 2.])
```

I curious about whats wrong with this code, maybe i missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to vectorize your function, and call it in a vectorized manner. So define

```
def fs(x):
    return np.stack([x[0,:]+ 2*x[1, :]-2, x[0, :]**2+4*x[1,:]**2-4])
```

and then call

```
x = np.array([[1.0, 2]])
output = jacobian(fs)(x)
```

But note that the `autograd` library is very outdated, doesn't have a very good documentation and is no longer maintained. I'd recommend using [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) or [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax) instead.

Comment: I'm very agree about 'autograd' are not have good documentation. It make me struggle bcs that. Moreover, I need jacobian for the broyden algorithm that I am currently making. Should I use JAX or Pytorch for jacobian? Btw i use numpy for my broyden algorithm.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JAX, and I'd recommend using PyTorch for starting out, as it has a more extensive documentation and a very large community of users and therefore resources. It is compatible with numpy, but for most projects you can basically replace numpy with pytorch.