# Derivative of Gaussian Blur with respect to the pixels

Tags: python, opencv, gaussianblur

I'm applying a Gaussian blur to an image where each pixel of the original image is being optimized for some purpose and the Gaussian blur is an intermediate transformation. For several reasons, it is important for me to be able to get the Jacobian of this transformation.

For instance if the transformation of the pixels can be given as G(p) then I need to be able to find dG/dp.

I'm stumped about how to actually find this though. It doesn't have to be analytical, it can be numerical through a Python program.

I don't really even know where to start.

I have an input image of 150x150 pixels. I am applying Gaussian blur through OpenCV. I understand how to find the Gaussian X and Y derivatives, but I don't understand how to find the `Jacobian` of the entire transformation with respect to the pixels.

Numerically, I suppose the finite difference method would work (change the pixel slightly and see the effect), but there probably is a better way no?

Comment: I think in principle, dG/dx should just be cv2.Sobel() on G for just x.  So make a Gaussian and then do the Nobel gradient in one or the other direction. Or get the Gaussian function and take its derivatives, then apply that to image.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553006/compute-the-jacobian-matrix-in-python

Comment: See also https://hannibunny.github.io/orbook/preprocessing/04gaussianDerivatives.html and https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6670/2011sp/lectures/lec02_filter.pdf

Comment: P.S. It should be more accurate to compute the digital approx. of the derivative of the gaussian and then apply that to an image, rather than apply the gaussian and then take the Sobel or some other derivative approximation.

Comment: Hi @fmw42, thanks for the response and all the material! Very useful. However, I am not sure I fully understand. dG/dx would calculate the gradient of the transformation with respect to the horizontal change in direction. Which I guess is useful. But I'm looking for the dG/dp where p indicates the intensity of the pixels. So how would change in pixel intensities cause a change in the Gaussian transformed matrix.

Comment: I believe that you would need to have the original image to have any hope. Even then I am not sure how you would even compute the derivative of one image relative to the other.

Comment: is this for neural networks/backpropagation/differentiability?